# Using Array from ViewController in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, arrays, object, viewcontroller, appdelegate

I have an array stored in the ViewController.m. But when the app enters background, i want to post notifications from the array.

so my NSMutableArray "list" was created in ViewController.m but i need to use in AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application




for (NSString *thing in list) {
    UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notif.alertBody = thing.text;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notif];
```

Answer (score 3):

If ViewController.m is your main VC:

```
ViewController *yourVC = (ViewController*)self.window.rootViewController;
yourVC.yourMutableArray = whateverYouWant;
```

I recommend saving the data inside of NSUserDefaults however, then you can just easily access it and read/write anywhere. BTW the presenting of localNotifications from that method in the appDelegate is a bad idea. The app store will not be a fan of immediate notifications when someone tries to leave an app..if you're even able to.

Comment: The code above should be put in the app delegate...But you should do what I said about NSUserDefaults instead.